# Alternative formula for specific heat

Tags: thermodynamics

In *The Theory of Quantum Liquids* Vol I by Pines and Nozieres pp. 20 Sec. 1.3, there is a derivation of the specific heat of Fermi liquid. I have a question in the first step:
They define the specific heat as: $C_v=(\partial E/\partial T)_N$. The next sentence reads:

> It is left as a problem to the reader to show that at low temperature $C_v$ may be put in the more convenient form $$C_v=(\partial F/\partial T)_\mu$$

They defined $F$ earlier as $F=E-\mu N$, the free energy and $\mu$ is the chemical potential. I have tried to use the formula for $F$ and the [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule) but am unable to reduce the derivative with constant $N$ to a derivative with constant $\mu$. Any help/hint is appreciated.